# My program gets an abort() error yet i cant debug it due to it being a loading part of the program?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int, srand

Every time i launch this application it goes to the menu which works perfect but then after i hit start() it just aborts and I have a theory that it is the stoi but I am not sure. As you can see I am making a game of blackjack and it uses the array to then rand() to randomize out of the array but then it has to convert the string from the array into an integer. But then you have to worry about kings or the 0 in the array so i had to account for that.

```
// Blackjack.cpp 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int start(); // forward decleration

int main() {
    int menu = 0;
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("BlackJack By Paul V 1.0"));
    cout << "Welcome to BlackJack!" << endl;
    cout << "1. Start the game!!" << endl;
    cout << "2. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "ENTER HERE:" << flush;
    cin >> menu;
    if (menu == 1) {
        start();
    }
    if (menu == 0) {
        cout << "Program Ending....." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int start() {
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("LOADING....."));
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int menu = 0;
    int yo1 = rand() % 13;
    int yo2 = rand() % 13;
    int yo3 = rand() % 13;
    int yo4 = rand() % 13;
    int yo5 = rand() % 13;
    int yo6 = rand() % 4;
    int yo7 = rand() % 4;
    int yo8 = rand() % 4;
    int yo9 = rand() % 4;
    int yo = rand() % 4;
    int card1 = 0;
    int card2 = 0;
    int card3 = 0;
    int card4 = 0;
    int card5 = 0;
    string card_names[13] = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    string card_types[4] = { "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts" };
    string goody = card_names[yo1];
    string goddy2 = card_names[yo2];
    string goddy3 = card_names[yo3];
    string goddy4 = card_names[yo4];
    string goddy5 = card_names[yo5];
    if (yo1 == 10 || yo1 == 11 || yo1 == 12) {
        const int card1 = 10;
    }
    if (yo2 == 10 || yo2 == 11 || yo2 == 12) {
        const int card2 = 10;
    }
    if (yo3 == 10 || yo3 == 11 || yo3 == 12) {
        const int card3 = 10;
    }
    if (yo4 == 10 || yo4 == 11 || yo4 == 12) {
        const int card4 = 10;
    }
    if (yo5 == 10 || yo5 == 11 || yo5 == 12) {
        const int card5 = 10;
    }
    if (yo1 == 0) {
        const int card1 = 1;
    }
    if (yo2 == 0) {
        const int card2 = 1;
    }
    if (yo3 == 0) {
        const int card3 = 1;
    }
    if (yo4 == 0) {
        const int card4 = 1;
    }
    if (yo5 == 0) {
        const int card5 = 1;
    }
    else {
        int card1 = stoi(card_names[yo1]);
        int card2 = stoi(card_names[yo2]);
        int card3 = stoi(card_names[yo3]);
        int card4 = stoi(card_names[yo4]);
        int card5 = stoi(card_names[yo5]);
    }
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("BlackJack By Paul V 1.0"));
    cout << "Your starting card is a " << goody << " of " << card_types[yo6] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know that your whole `if`/`else` chain is useless, right?

Comment: Why is it useless?

Comment: Oh I see exactly why it is useless due to me defining the variables before I go through the chain! Thanks for that fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your stoi(). It's because the values for yo'n' follow through into the last "else" part of your code even when they are beyond the 1 to 9 range.

You need to do a range check for all yo'n' variables before passing them to stoi as card_names[yo'n'].

As smead said, Please write cleaner code. so much 'if' makes it barely readable and debug-able.

Answer (score 1):

`stoi()` converts a string to a number, but only if your string can be validly converted to a number ([see documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)). Your array `card_names` contains several non-integer strings ("Ace", "Jack", etc.).

I'm not even sure what you're trying to do there: your values `yo1` through `yo5` already contain the card numbers, so why do you need to convert it to a string and back?

And by the way, please use arrays! It hurts my eyes to see things like `yo1` through `yo9` and `card1` through `card5` :)